# Swift/Firebase Converting the snapshots (JSON) into Excel

Tags: json, swift, excel, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

does anyone here knows of a good method to convert Firebase data into excel format? Ideally I would like to do this by function call, such that I can pull the JSON database from Firebase and convert them into excel format.

Taking my JSON from Firebase as an example:

```
Snap (-KQc-qqY3qc6ZQgQQ4EF) {
    DOB = "01/09/2016";
    purpose = "No purpose";
    name = "Adam";
    timeOfVisit = 1803;
    userID = LV6aANvLfAcTXTDpsZr5R4viUnE2;
}
```

When a user taps a 'export to excel' button, I would like to grab the JSON file from Firebase and convert it to excel file. Subsequently I would like to send this file to the user via email.

```
@IBAction func exportToExcel(sender: AnyObject) {
    let dataSnapshot: FIRDataSnapshot! = self.database[indexPath.row]
    let databaseValues = dataSnapshot.value as! Dictionary< String, AnyObject>

    let name = databaseValues["name"] as! String!
    let time = databaseValues["timeOfVisit"] as! Int!
    let DOB = databaseValues["DOB"] as! String!
    let purpose = databaseValues["purpose"] as! String!

    // parse above variables into individual rows in excel file

}
```

Comment: Where do you want to do the conversion e.g. in Excel, or via webpage?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I would like to do it via my app. For instance, a user can tap a button and exports the database as an excel file and send it to his/her email.

Comment: Please provide some code or more information on how you plan to do this.

Comment: @GJZ Pls see edit. Above edit is more of a possible sample approach. As of now I can't really find any excel parsers, do you happen to know any? Appreciate your advice pls.

Comment: @Koh - Excel can easily read comma separated values or tab delimited files. You could look at creating a file type like that for your export. Do you really need output file format to be xlsx?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Ideally yes because its targetted at non-techies. Alternatively what file types can i export to such that its 'openable' in excel?

Comment: @Koh - go for .csv files (comma separated values)

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm looking for the same thing.